# How to delete duplicated lines for a specified line, and without sorting?

Tags: shell, awk

I understand using `awk '!a[$0]++' file` to delete duplicated lines with the original order remaining, but such command works for entire file but I want to do this for a specified line.

For example, I have a file `LINE` listing several lines:

```
line1
line2
line3
```

I want delete the duplicated lines that are listed in `LINES` in another file `FILE`. For example, the `FILE` has such lines:

```
line1
line2
line3
line4
line4
line4
line1
line1
line2
line3
```

After deleting, first six lines are remaining since `line4` is not in `LINES`, so it's duplication would not be cleaned.

Thanks very much for the help!

Answer (score 2):

You can write something like

```
awk 'FNR==NR{lines[$0]++; next} lines[$0]++ < 2' lines file
```

---

```
$ awk 'FNR==NR{lines[$0]++; next} lines[$0]++ < 2' lines file
line1
line2
line3
line4
line4
```

Comment: Thanks for your kind response! The command almost works :), only with one problem: from above example, for the lines not in `LINES`， it only print them twice.

Comment: I fixed it with a kind of naive way: `awk 'FNR==NR{lines[$0]++; next} $0 in a{if(lines[$0]++ < 2){print $0}} !($0 in a){print $0}' lines file`